# Using aptana to debug with easyphp +cakephp

Tags: php, cakephp, aptana, easyphp

I'm starting a new project, for this project, I need a great IDE, which allows me to debug. I thought to aptana after some search.

But this project is a little specific, it has to work with a specific version of php and has not common extension(e.g. php_ingres), so I think I cannot use the internal server of aptana, otherwise it will not find every ingres function.

I've an EasyPhp environnement installed and working.

I've created a new "Simple server" and a new web browser configuration using this webserver(and chrome). But now when I try to debug it, I cannot see my browser configuration, it looks like it display only internal servers here. So is this possible to use aptana with easyphp? If yes, how?

If not, which IDE provide some auto-completion, debugging and allows me to use my own server?

Thank you very much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally used code lobster, which is not the best editor but can use easyPhp and actually debug into it.

Answer (score 2):

I think Netbeans can do your job, check this guide :

http://wiki.netbeans.org/HowToConfigureXDebug

Comment: Okay, I made some tries and it sounds like it's better, it stops on my first line. But if I put some breakpoint in a method which is executed , this isn't called. I cannot just wait on the first line, because with cake php, we go through a lot of methods each time

Comment: where is the method with the breakpoint? Is it in the same project?.

Comment: I ask the above, as if the method is in a separate project, or in files not part of the project, you need to add them to the include path for the project in Netbeans for the debugging to work.

Comment: Hi,

Yes, it's a cake php framework, so we go through a lot of files and a lot of methods, but this is all the same project.

Answer (score 0):

Netbeans is great and is free too. But it maybe hard to figure your way around in that for a 1st time user. If money ain't a problem i'd suggest using phpDesigner 7 - http://www.mpsoftware.dk/phpdesigner.php. Easy and simple, with word completion, debugging features and also allows you to setup up an FTP connection to your servers so you can edit your files on the fly.(This method of editing files on the fly however may not be ideal if its mission critical data. I'd suggest using version control platforms like git, read more here - http://progit.org/book/ch1-1.html  )

Comment: In fact my biggest problem is that I need that the php which runs the "debug" mode has the "ingres" extension. so either I can use my easyphp to debug or the internal debug server has ingres

Comment: isn't easyphp a wamp package(i'd suggest using WAMP which is easier to install). So if you configure it properly to read php files on localhost and keep your projects in the localhost folder everything should run smoothly and debugging files in the project won't be a problem either. But make sure you include all external files, if any, that is required by the project in file>>project properties>>PHP Include Path.

Comment: EasyPhp is more compatible with php_ingres and the version of ingres that we have to implement. Wamp was needing the exact version of the dll for its php version(which doesn't exists).
Like I said to fb1, it seems that the only breaking point that netbeans is stopping on is the first line executed, every other breakpoint in any other file(which are in the project) aren't executed.

What's about phpDesigner for debuging?